# Android Weather / News stopped working claiming it doesn't know where I am

Tags: news-and-weather

Today I noticed that my Google Weather no longer shows me a weather forecast.  Instead of each day showing a weather condition and a forecast high/low temperatures, I just shows "--" in each day's slot.

When I tap on it to bring up the app, it doesn't show me anything either.  Instead, it says:

```
You have no local sections. Sign in to add local 
sections or turn on location services to see news 
about your current location.
```

But when I tap on the side bar to bring up settings, it clearly shows that I am signed in.  Also location services are already turned on!

I tried switching to a different account, and this caused news and weather to show up.  But all the news was at least two weeks old, and whenever I tap on the weather to try to bring up details it says "News & Weather has stopped"  When I refresh everything goes away and I see the above message again.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has stopped supporting "Google News & Weather" in favor of the new "Google News" product.  Once the switch happened, the app itself does not make it clear what has happened.  You have to tap on the "Headlines" tab (which is unintuitive), at which point the only top story is "We're no longer supporting Google News & Weather".

It also says, "Tap to switch to Google News" but in my experience tapping on this doesn't do anything.